# What all triggers the game to save?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Obviously, you can save the game manually at points of interest, and it saves for you whenever you get out of your ship. I also found out that it saves after you die (gee, thanks). Are there any other events that cause the game to be saved?

Answer (score 4):

Using the save points and getting out of your ship are the only two ways I know of that will save the game. Aside from dying, as you've pointed out in the question, I do not know of any other ways to trigger the auto-save.

I found an article that confirms what I've said above.

> During our time with the game so far, however, we’ve noticed that it looks like it creates a new save whenever you get into or out of your ship, and whenever you discover a new building or structure.

Source: http://twinfinite.net/2016/08/no-mans-sky-is-there-autosaving/

Comment: Neither of those events (in the quote) creates a save point in my 40+ hours of experience playing it. Only using a specific save point or getting out of your ship.

Comment: I think the quote meant using the save point AT new building/structures; didn't catch that, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I don't think so. It seems to be talking about autosave and that doesn't occur around buildings, new or not.

Comment: @tubedogg - you don't really "discover" a building until you interact with the savepoint/beacon, so that's probably what they meant

Comment: @HorusKol That I would agree with, though explicitly choosing to interact with the save post is in no way autosaving, but I think we can probably agree not everybody on the internet writes as clearly or correctly as they should. :)

Comment: @tubedogg - having read the full article, it doesn't sound like they're claiming it to be autosave - just that there is autosave, and that interacting with building beacons also saves...

Comment: @HorusKol The following sentence is "Therefore, you can rest assured [progress will not be lost] if that power plug comes out..." The only way for that to be true is if it's autosaved. Then "Unfortunately, the ['Restore Point Saved' message] doesn’t show when discovering a new building...but from our own experience, the game does still autosave at this point." The message ALWAYS shows when using a beacon. So they can't be talking about that. And the rest of the article is about autosave because one of the last lines mentions saving manually as an alternative to trusting the game's autosave.